# How to create a dynamic form with values in model using form.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to create a dynamic form using forms.py where questions and answers come from values in the columns of models.

I have three models, one called Sheet, which contains many questions from the Question model  (Many to Many). The Question model can contain one or more answers from the Answer model (Many to Many)

In my views.py, my function retrieves all values from Sheet model and sends values to my html file.

In my html file I have a code that allows me to display all the questions with their answers.

```
class Sheet(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question, blank=True)
    sheet_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sheet_name


class Question(models.Model):
    is_parent = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
    answer = models.ManyToManyField(Answer, blank=True)
    in_french = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    in_english = models.TextField(max_length=512)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.in_french


class Answer(models.Model):
    in_french = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    in_english = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.in_french
```

```
{% for a_sheet in all_sheets %}
    <b>Survey: {{ a_sheet.sheet_name}}</b>
        {% for q in a_sheet.question.all %}
            <label>Question: {{ q.in_english }}</label><br/>
            <label>Answers:</label>
            {% if q.answer.all %}
                <select> 
                    {% for a in q.answer.all %}  
                        <option value={{ a.id }}> {{ a.in_french }} </option> 
                    {% endfor %} 
                </select>
            {% else%}
             <input type="text" name="answer">
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how to translate my html code to put it in my forms.py file. Putting the code in a function of my forms.py file would allow me to set up conditions and retrieve the results of my form to put them in another model. This problem cannot be solved by default with the forms.ModelForm which displays the model columns in the forms.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What is the form supposed to submit, in other words what's the exact input of the user? If it's just an answer, then a ModelForm for the Answer model works perfectly. If it's a new Question with multiple new Answers, then maybe a Question ModelForm and an inlineformset of Answers could be the approach (you'd have to create and process both in your view). Think of it in terms of the input data that will be submitted.

Comment: Also why is `answers` a m2m relationship? Can the same answers be used for multiple questions? Wouldn't a foreign key to `Question` be a more logical approach?

Comment: @dirkgroten : Hello, the inputs of the user come from the Answer model (values like "red", "blue"...). Have you an example of a ModelForm for this problem? I tried, with no results... 
For the m2m relationship, a question can have multiple answers, and a answer can be in multiple questions.

Comment: So the user is choosing an answer from the existing answers? And then what? You save the user's choice? Or just tell him if the answer is correct without saving anything? You have to describe more specifically what the application you're building is going to do.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes he is choosing an existing answer from Answer model. After I want a POST method which saves values in a ResultSurvey model with "id_question", "id_answer" (both are ForeignKey from Question and Answer models).

Comment: Then the form to use is a ModelForm for `ResultSurvey` where the `question` is already pre-filled (hidden input field).